# Orthogonal projection matrix raised to a power

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I am asked to find the 2x2 matrix A that represents an orthogonal projection onto the line $f(x)=-\sqrt{3}x$, and then find $A^{1001}$. I have found A and tried multiplying it out a couple times to deduce a pattern but haven't got anywhere.

Thinking geometrically, once the projection is performed the first time, wouldn't any subsequent projection be represented by a zero matrix because it's not going anywhere? With that in mind, what approach am I missing to find $A^{1001}$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Notice that the unit vector $e=\frac12(1,-\sqrt3)$ spans the given line. Now, let $(e_1,e_2)$ the standard basis of $\Bbb R^2$ then the first column of $A$ is given by

$$(e_1\cdot e)e=\frac12 e$$
and the second column of $A$ is given by
$$(e_2\cdot e)e=-\frac{\sqrt3}2 e$$
Hence, we have
$$A=\begin{pmatrix}\frac14&-\frac{\sqrt3}4\\
-\frac{\sqrt3}4& \frac34\end{pmatrix}$$
Finally, since $A$ is a projection matrix then $A^2=A$ (*you can verify it*) and so we get $A^{1001}=A$.

Comment: Thank you, this makes sense. So would $A^{2}=A$ also apply to a reflection matrix, like a reflection over the line $f(x)=-\sqrt{3}x$?

Comment: @DominicHicks No! Reflections satisfy $A^2=I$—you undo a reflection by reflecting again.